# How to push one array object value into another inside a loop using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I need one help.I need to push one array object value into another array object in each iteration using PHP.I am explaining my code below.

```
for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++){
 while($report=mysqli_fetch_assoc($reportqry)){
        $result[]=$report;
    }
  //$arry
}
```

Here i need the `$result` will push into `$arry` in each iteration of the loop.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

use `array_push` function ([PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-push.php))

```
while($report=mysqli_fetch_assoc($reportqry)){
    array_push($result, $report);
}
```

Comment: @ Wartus : What  need of $report here.

Comment: what i need here `$result` is containing some array of values.So i need to move those array of values to another array object .

Comment: @subhra $report is the value that you want to insert in the array $result

Answer (score 0):

```
$reportqry=mysqli_query(' some sql ');

$len=5;

$arry=array();/* was this defined before attempting to push items onto stack? */
$result=array();/* also define before loop */

for( $i=0; $i < $len; $i++ ){
    while( $report=mysqli_fetch_assoc( $reportqry ) ){
        $result[]=$report;
    }
    $arry[]=$result;
}
```

I tested the above and it appears to operate as expected - but I'm not 100% sure I have grasped the concept.

my test:

```
$sql='select `username`,`description` from `tasks`';
$results=$conn->query( $sql );
$len=3;

$arry=array();
$result=array();

for( $i=0; $i < $len; $i++ ){
    while( $rs=$results->fetch_assoc() ){
        $result[]=$rs;
    }
    $arry[]=$result;
}
```

Result of printing `$arry`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [username] => fred
                    [description] => banana
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [username] => joe
                    [description] => apple
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [username] => bertrum
                    [description] => orange
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [username] => fred
                    [description] => banana
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [username] => joe
                    [description] => apple
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [username] => bertrum
                    [description] => orange
                )
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [username] => fred
                    [description] => banana
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [username] => joe
                    [description] => apple
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [username] => bertrum
                    [description] => orange
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: No,I checked it before.its not coming properly.

Comment: Are you wanting to iterate through the recordset $len times and add multiple copies to an array? Why the outer loop?

Comment: `$len` is some multiple id present inside a array.Suppose for 1st iteration using 0th index id multiple data presnt inside `$result` then it will aqppend to another array type object as 0 th index then for 2nd iteration all data again push into array object as 1st index and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++){
 while($report=mysqli_fetch_assoc($reportqry)){

    array_push(result = $report);
}


//$arry
}
```